# UnwindSegue doesn't work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I'm trying to enable a segue such that if a user presses cancel on the sign up page, it takes them back to the login page.

On my login view controller I have:

```
- (IBAction)unwindToLogIn:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
}
```

However, when I press the cancel button it doesn't work. I've done the connection in Interface Builder that connects the cancel button the green exit thingy in the view. It still isn't working- any idea of what's going on?

Comment: What is your view controller hierarchy? How did the user get from login page to sign up page in the first place?

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them) might help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an identifier to your segue in IB then just do

```
- (IBAction)unwindToLogin{
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: ended up just changing it to [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

Comment: That make sense I would have done the same unless I would be looking to send some data with the segue